# Multi level Promise in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a problem with promise

I want to get all Category and sub Category ( Multi level Category) using promise. But i can't get multi level promise. I can get first Promise use Promise.all(Array) but can't get child promise.

```
    getChild: function(_cats){
   var arrCat=[];
   var that = this;
   for (var i = 0, len = _cats.length; i < len; i++) { 
    var t = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
     var a = [];
     var _c = _cats[i];

     _cats[i].getChildren(function(err, _childs){

      a.push({
        root: _c,
        child:  that.getChild(_childs)
      });
     resolve(a);
   })
   })
    arrCat.push (t);
  }
  return Promise.all(arrCat);
```

and other function to call and respon api:

```
this.getChild(_cats).then(_r => {
  return res.ok(_r);  
})
```

and the respone

```
[{
root: {value} // it's ok
child: promise(pending) //it's problem
}]
```

Please help me! thank you!

Comment: which one is the child promise ?

Comment: Sorry for the bad English. i want to get promise in child array. thanks Marvel

Answer (score 2):

First extract promisified version of `cat.getChildren` to make code clear. Then map over all categories and for each category return a Promise that resolves only after every nested child is loaded by recursively calling `getChild`. Something like this should do the trick

```js
function getChildren(cat) {
  new Promise(function(resolve) {
    cat.getChildren(function(_, children) {
      resolve(children)
    })
  })
}

getChild: function getChild(_cats) {
  return Promise.all(
    _cats.map(function(cat) {
      return getChildren(cat)
        .then(getChild) // load each child
        .then(function(children) {
          return {
            root: cat,
            children: children
          }
        })
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work perfect. Thanks to Yury

```js
function getChildren(cat) {
  new Promise(function(resolve) {
    cat.getChildren(function(_, children) {
      resolve(children)
    })
  })
}

getChild: function getChild(_cats) {
  return Promise.all(
    _cats.map(function(cat) {
      return getChildren(cat)
        .then(getChild) // load each child
        .then(function(children) {
          return {
            root: cat,
            children: children
          }
        })
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: You could simply accept my answer instead of copy/pasting it :)

Comment: you names flipped, Children means multiple, but it's actually getting only one, and Child is a chain of calls,  ................